# How does ios know which xib/nib to load?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an ios app that has a target of both iphone and ipad.  I have a class that has a .xib for both iphone and ipad. how does the app know which xib/nib? where is the magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your files are named `foo.xib` and `foo~ipad.xib`, then the magic is just code in either `UIViewController` or `NSBundle` that appends `~ipad` to the end of the name when the current device is an iPad. It's nothing hugely complex, just a convenience.

Comment: So by sticking with the naming convention we dont have to do anything extra?  If I add a new class with a nib, do I just do a copy of the nib and rename it with the ~ipad?  What is the preferred way of adding an additional .xib for the ipad when you already have one for the iphone?

Comment: never mind -- just noticed I can just do add file  -> application nib